# shell cmd : " seq 1 9 | touch " doesn't work?

Tags: bash, shell

I just want create some new file named 1 to 9.
but why

```
% seq 1 9 | touch
```

doesn't work?
and

```
% seq 1 9 | xargs touch

% touch $(seq 1 9)
```

work. But why?

Comment: I think it's really a good question, but now it marked as off-topic, :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `touch` reads the argument list and not the standard input. [Relevant manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/touch/)

Answer (score 4):

```
> man touch
touch [OPTION]... FILE...
```

`touch` expects the list of the file it should create, on the command line.

That's what `xargs` does. That's also what the shell expansion `$()` you use does.

However that's not what the pipe does: it redirects the output of the previous command on the input of the next; not on the arguments provided.

You may get a better understanding with this script:

```
echo "Command line: " $*
read input
echo "Input: " $input
```

You can then try to run it to see how both are handled:

```
> echo "tata" | ./temp.sh toto
Command line:  toto
Input:  tata
```

Comment: ``touch {1..9}`` is the best solution anyway :)